# Is there a way to read its value at backend in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, database, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
              <v-autocomplete
              @change="bindForm"
            v-model="form1.country"
              :items="countries"
              item-value="1" 
              item-text="0"
              :label="$t('Country Code')">
            </v-autocomplete>
    data() {
      
      return {
        countries: [
          ['United States(+1)','+1'],
          ['Canada(+1)','+1'],
          ['Australia(+61)','+61'],
          ['United Kingdom(+44)','+44'],
          ['Nepal(+977)','+977'],
          ['India(+91)','+91'],
          ['Austria(+43)','+43'],
          ['Belgium(+32)','+32'],
          ['Brazil(+55)','+55'],
        ],
  country:[],
form1:{
country:''
}
}
}
methods:{
      bindForm(selectedValue) {
        this.form.country = selectedValue;

  }
}
```

How can I read the value of this  at backend in laravel.
I tried to read the value of it at backend but it is showing null in response.
What are the possible ways to solve this.

Comment: `How can I read the value of this ` what is `this` in that sentence? How are you integrating Vue with Laravel? Can you please explain those?

Comment: I mean like in `input` we have attribute `name` to read the value of input at backend. In the same way how can I read the value of `v-autocomplete` in backend using laravel

Comment: `v-autocomplete` is using `v-model` which is bonded with `form1.country`, so you can pass that value in your API request.